# Create dynamic method that takes argument

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is it possible to declare dynamic methods with `define_method` that does an `instance_exec` of a block with arguments ? Something like this :

```
class D
  def self.adapt (method,*args,&impl)
    define_method(method) do 
      instance_exec(args,impl)
    end
  end
end

D.adapt(:foo,a,b) { a + b }

puts D.new.foo(1,2)
```

Comment: Please indent your code with two-spaces:)

Comment: It is done, sorry for that ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
class D < Struct.new(:c)
  def self.adapt (method, &impl)
    define_method(method) do |*args|
      instance_exec(*args, &impl)
    end
  end
end

D.adapt(:foo) { |a, b| a + b + c }

puts D.new(3).foo(1, 2)
# => 6
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to subclass from `Struct.new(:c)`?

Comment: It isn't. It's to show that the block given to `D.adapt` can access `D`'s instance variables.